# Is this a valid Geometric proof?

Tags: geometry, proof-verification, contest-math

This problem is from the European Girls Mathematics Olympiad.

Problem 1; Let $ABC$ be a triangle with Circumcentre $O$, the points $D, E, F$ lie in the interiors of sides $BC, AC, AB$, respectively, such that $DE$ is perpendicular to $CO$ and $DF$ is perpendicular to $BO$, let $K$ be the Circumcentre of triangle $ARE$. Prove that lines $DK$ and $BC$ are perpendicular.

My solution
Let line segment $DK$ meet $BC$ at point $M$, it is required to prove that $\angle KMB = 90^{\circ}$

Proof
Draw a line segment line $l$ passing through point $B$ such that $\measuredangle lBC = 90^{\circ}$, through $K$, dropped a perpendicular $KP$ on $l$. Using a well known theorem that triangles on the same base and between the same parallels are congruent, it follows that triangles $PKM$ and $PMB$ are congruent, hence $\measuredangle PMK = \measuredangle KMB$, from which it follows that points $P, K, M, B$ are Concyclic, but since $\measuredangle BPK = 90^{\circ}$,  it follows that $B$ is a diameter, since points $B, K, M$ are Concyclic, it follows that $\measuredangle BMK = 90^{\circ}$, as desired.

Comment: You have to put spaces between `\???` and the next object if the next object starts with letters. In addition, there is no mathjax for degrees unfortunately, so you need to copy paste `°` each time

Comment: Note:  " ^ \circ"  looks ok.  That is "90^\circ" compiles to $90^\circ$

Comment: I suggest <code>\widehat{ABC}</code> for rendering $\widehat{ABC}$ and <code>90^\circ</code> for rendering $90^\circ$.

Comment: It's nice to have an accompanying figure.

Comment: Triangles on the same base and between the same parallels are equal in area but not generally congruent.

Comment: First of all, there is a typo --- what is R? Most importantly, even if you have  proven (that proof may not be valid)  that $\measuredangle BMK = 90^{\circ}$, you are still not answering the required --- "DK and BC are perpendicular".

Comment: @Mick, yeah my proof was absurd and I have corrected it.

Comment: 1) Typo has not been fixed -- where is R in $\triangle ARE$? 2) The question is asking for "DK and BC ...." and I can't find D anywhere in your proof.